# Dynamically rendering React component within HTML

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, there's a module that renders `HTML`. I created the following little function in the component that renders the `HTML`.

```
renderContent(content) {
  return { __html: content }
}
```

And here's how I call it:

```
<div className="padding-20" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderContent(this.props.myContent)}></div>
```

This has worked so far because the section within the component where I needed to render `HTML` was separated within a particular `<div>`.

Now, I'd like to render a component, specifically a `<form>` within this `HTML` section and the form itself is in a separate component. Trying to figure out how I can do this.

I think I could set an `id` to a `<div>` or use specific class that indicates the existence of a component and somehow render the component there. Has anyone tackled this before? If so, I'd appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a few variables. Some Points of clarification with answers depending on your needs.

1. This form is a React component?  Or is it raw HTML?
2. Ir exists to in ComponentA and you’d like to render it in ComponentB?

[React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) are the solution designed for this exact problem. They allow you to render content from one component to anywhere else in the DOM.

If you use a portal, I don’t believe passing raw HTML will work. Instead, pass as the first argument a div setting your form using dangerouslySetInnerHtml.

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to do is to render one component in another but currently the "parent" component is only rendering `HTML`. Maybe a context is useful here. I have a `BlogViewer` component that simply renders the content of a blog post which is `HTML` and it contains typical text, image and video content contained in a blog entry. All of this data, including the video, are simply `HTML` code. For example, video could simply be a YouTube video embedded thru `iframe`. What I want to do now is to be able include a form which is a separate React component.

Comment: I also want to mention that the idea with the form is to place it at a certain spot in the HTML content so that it flows well with the design. The form component is a `class` component and has all the necessary logic to collect data and process it through my backend API. So, I need to figure out a way to "inject" a React component into a parent component BUT the trick is that the parent component treats the data it receives as `HTML`. Clearly, I need to change this behavior so that form component will get rendered properly.

Comment: To give you an example, say I figure out a way to tell my parent component that in addition to regular `HTML` data, there's a React component that needs to be rendered/displayed in the blog post. I, then, have the necessary logic to indicate the precise location of where the component needs to be rendered e.g. `<div id="myComponent"></div>`. What I need to achieve is that the parent component will render all the content as `HTML` except when it sees that there's another component that goes with the content, it injects it into `<div id="myComponent"></div>`. Hope this clarifies it further.

Comment: React uses a unidirectional data flow, meaning everything gets rendered top to bottom. The only way out of this is with a Portal. A Portal inserts what you render directly into a DOM node, meaning that node may be in a parent, but the parent cannot see what is being inserted, it doesn’t even know it is happening. All of the logic for what gets rendered where will have to live where the Portal is

Comment: What you’re doing pushes against the edge of the central a paradigm React uses: unidirectional data flow. The reason for this paradigm is it decouples components, data, and the methods for how things end up in the DOM. I would recommend taking a step back and re-evaluating if you can do solve this without this conditional parent/child interaction. What you are describing sounds like it will end up hard to maintain in the long wrong.